# Htaccess URL rewrite www.website.com/info/index.php to info.website.com

Tags: php, .htaccess, file, web

I have no clue where to find how to do that. Is it even possible?
On 1 domain? Or I just must buy another domain with domain address "info.website.com" ?

Or if you can send me website with informations about htaccess.
I know I must add code act. for stackoverflow.com rules.

Comment: info.website.com is a subdomain of a website.com domain. You should create a subdomain in your server configuration first.

Answer (score 0):

Use this rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule info.website.com www.website.com/info/index.php [L,R=301]
```

Also you need to create a subdomain "info" on your web server.